# QWizard: Confirmation on back button

Tags: c++, qt

I've created a wizard by subclassing QWizard, and I created pages of my wizard by subclassing QWizardPage.

I would like to show a confirmation dialog when the user press the **Back** button, and I want my wizard to not go to the previous page if the user press **no** on the confirmation dialog.

When clicking **Next** on a QWizard dialog, the virtual function `bool validatePage()` is called and allows to return false if we don't want to go to the next page (for example when there is an incomplete field).

However, when pressing **Back**, I don't know any way to say "Don't go back". The virtual function `void cleanupPage()` is called (I can ask the user confirmation here), but the Wizard will go back anyway.

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I finally achieve what I wanted (not sure this is the best way...) by disconnecting the back button signal, and connecting it to my custom slot.

```
MyWizard::MyWizard(QWidget *parent) : QWizard(parent)
{
   // [...]
   connect(this, SIGNAL(currentIdChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onPageChanged(int)));
}

void MyWizard::onPageChanged(int id)
{
    disconnect(button(BackButton), SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), 0, 0);
    connect(button(BackButton), SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(onBackButtonClicked()));
}

void MyWizard::onBackButtonClicked()
{
    if (currentId() > Page_Intro && !confirmation(tr("Are you sure you want to go back?")))
        return;
    back();
}
```

Note that if you do the connection/disconnection on the Wizard constructor, it does not work (Qt connect it when you pass the first page).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with *void QWizardPage::setCommitPage(bool commitPage)* function. This function prevents user to going back on the page. Set it on cleanupPage() of the wizard:

```
MyWizard::cleaupPage(int id) 
{
    //Test here if 'id' is the page that you want and the do the following

    if(QMessageBox::question(...) == QMessageBox::Yes)
       this->page(id)->setCommitPage(false);
    else
       this->page(id)->setCommitPage(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't works (it still go back...)

Comment: This will disable the **Back** button that has already been clicked.